# Ctrl+Click on a function name in Atom editor and jump into it

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, atom-editor

I've been trying to think of a better way to title this question, but unfortunately I have no idea how to explain it. Also I haven't found this on stack overflow (for the same reason stated above).

In Eclipse, I used to **Ctrl+Click** in the name of a method call (in java). And my cursor would jump in to the definition of my method function.

Question 1: Does anyone know the name of this behavior? I mean, maybe it's called function jumping or something like that.

Also I was searching for a plugin like this in Atom editor. Because I've tried to use this a lot of times (bad habits) and didn't work.

Question 2: Name of the plugin to do this in Atom?

Don't know if it helps, but I'm coding in JavaScript at the moment in Atom editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other answer noted, alt-click over a method/function name can jump you directly to where it was originally defined. It works within the same file, but  it doesn't seem to work across files.

The closest Atom editor package I've found for javascript which allows you to jump to function/method definitions across files is called [TernJS](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs).

Once installed, you can use `ctrl-shift-r` over the word (function/method, variable etc) to bring up a list of where that method/function is defined (includes line # & filepath). You can then click on the list item & it will jump you to the definition.

Here is a video I made containing an example of using this atom package.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFAzqvYoHJs&t=11m58s

Comment: Thank you sir, it's not the best solution but it is a solution that works. I finally switched to Visual Studio Code (vscode) editor because it has this 'Ctrl+Click' feature.

Comment: No problem - I'm going to check out Visual studio code for that feature you mentioned.

Comment: Oh sorry sir, maybe you misunderstood me. I mean that "Visual Studio Code" (Microsoft's open source editor) has this "Ctrl+Click" feature built-in, in to the application itself.  So it's okay, you don't need to find this feature for me :)
My apologies, English is not my main language.

Comment: To be honest this is the main reason I don't use Atom. IntelliJ does this by default and so does Visual Code.

Comment: @chovy - yeah it sucks that this isn't a built-in feature of Atom. I hope the Atom team adopts the 'language servers' per language concept soon. This would allow for intelligent language features to implemented on a plugin-based method.

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensions/example-language-server

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question this '*behavior*' is knows as 'go to definition', or 'jump to definition'.

To answer your second question some packages you could perhaps take a look at would be,

- ['goto-definition'](https://atom.io/packages/goto-definition)
- ['code-peek'](https://atom.io/packages/code-peek)

I find these help a bit but still don't achieve the standards that I would fully like. I wanted something similar to the Intellij IDEA <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click.

I find myself using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to search the entire project for the related files of the thing I'm searching for. Then I find the particular file i'm looking for and ***shazam***! I've got what I came to get. This particular method works best for me.

I know its not exactly what your looking for but this is the best thing I've found so far to achieve something similar to what we both seem to be looking for. Hope this helps a bit, 
*happy coding...*

Answer (score 1):

Currently this behavior is blocked by [multiple cursors feature](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/7595).
The closest you can get is "ctrl-alt-shift-d" + `atom-ternjs`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I have a package for that.

Simply `ctrl-D` goes to definition for me.

Tried by luck after reading here other methods.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try atom/navigate

[Link to Atom Navigate](https://atom.io/packages/navigate)

It helps you to do this excact thing.

The only thing is that it's default key is f2 instead of cltr+click

But this is also editable in the package settings in de .atom file

Answer (score 0):

In Atom (1.57.0 version, os Ubuntu 18.04) command ctrl+shift+f is doing project-find:show. (try cmd+shift+f if on mac and the above does not work)

First select a function name in a file within a project, click ctrl+shift+f, and a list of files from your project folder, that also have this function (either defined, or used) should appear.
Click on any of these files, to come back to the list use ctrl+tab. I can see in key-bindings that this command project-find:show, is bound to ctrl+shift+f, and I have used it, but I am not sure if this is from one of the packages, or not. (sorry new to atom)